# Display day along with date in datepicker plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui, datepicker

I'm using a datepicker from jQuery UI and customizing its CSS according to my needs. In almost all datepicker they show only dates like(23/7/2015) when click on a day but what i want is that i want to customize the datepicker plugin to show the day along with the date like (Wed 23/7/2015). 
I have limited knowledge of jQuery and couldn't find anything on how to achieve this. 
Here is my jQuery code:

```
$(function(){
    $('#datepicker').datepicker({           
        inline: true,
        showOtherMonths: false,
        dayNamesMin: ['Su', 'Mo', 'Tu', 'We', 'Th', 'Fr', 'Sa'],
    });
});
```

Here is an image of the date picker i want to make: [IMAGE.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zJjis.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the dateFormat option to alter the display, like so: `dateFormat: "D dd/mm/yy"`

```
$(function(){    
    $('.datepicker').datepicker({
        dateFormat: "D dd/mm/yy"        
    });    
});
```

Example: [JS Fiddle Example](http://jsfiddle.net/LyndseyB/9f6t2uqy/1/)

Reference: https://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#option-dateFormat

Comment: Thank you very much. Works like a charm.

Answer (score 1):

This should work for you :

```
$(function(){
    $('#datepicker').datepicker({  
        dateFormat:"D MM/dd/yyyy",         
        inline: true,
        showOtherMonths: false,
    });
});
```

Checkout this [JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mg8fn95a/)